# Trying to work out whether a rectangle will fit within half of a circle.

Tags: geometry

Probably a really simple question, but I am trynig to fit an air bed in a tent.

Circular tent with a diameter of $3$m and a central vertical pole in the middle.

The air bed measures $1.41$ m $\times$ $1.9$ m.

Will the air bed fit fully inside the tent without being obstructed by the central pole?

Comment: Is height not an issue? If yes, how tall is the tent (is it a true hemisphere) and how tall is the bed?

Answer (score 1):

It won't. Consider a quarter of the circle with half bed. The corner of the bed will be $\sqrt{1.41^2+\left(\frac{1.9}{2}\right)^2}\approx1.7$ meters distant from the tent's center. It's radius is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not a computation, but I constructed an approximate picture (the relative dimensions should be correct up to $0.01$m):
[image]
I think in this case a proof by sketch might be ok. It will *not* fit in.